# PhPmail headers showing in message while I do not want them to ;)

Tags: header, phpmailer

I have the following headers for emails sent with phpmailer:

```
    $headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $subject = EMAIL_SUBJECT ;
```

I pass them like this (standard it seems...):

```
    mail(EMAIL_TO, $subject , stripslashes($message), $headers);
```

As a result my mail is perfectly sent the subject from etc appear but in the main body of the message before the html starts, I get:

Message-Id: Date: Thu, 8 Dec 2011 08:55:33 +0100 (CET) Return-Path: my@email.org X-OriginalArrivalTime: 08 Dec 2011 08:04:43.0526 (UTC) FILETIME=[0B336260:01CCB580]

I could not get rid of it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code as follow:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\n";
```

Notice, I removed the \r of the Content-type line and changed the order of the headers.